# google translate api error 400

Tags: php, curl, google-api

I am getting below error in google translator api while tranlating a webpage content. Please let me know how to get rid of the following error.

making curl request giving below error

```
<?php
      CURLOPT_URL => 
      "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=KEY",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => data,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET'),
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>60,
       ));
?>
```

response

```
{
    error: {
        code: 400,
        message: "Text too long",
        errors: [
            {
                message: "Text too long",
                domain: "global",
                reason: "invalid"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$data`?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    error: {
        code: 400,
        message: "Text too long",
        errors: [
            {
                message: "Text too long",
                domain: "global",
                reason: "invalid"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you read the error message it states "Text too long"

There is a limit to how much data can be translated at a time.  If memory serves that limit is around  5,000 characters.

Solution send less data.